# Swiperight and swipeleft gestures for slideshow from w3school

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swipe-gesture

I have a problem with jquery swiperight and swipeleft gestures.

I have two slideshows, first one is Bootstrap Carousel and second one is inspiration from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_imgdots).

[(codepen)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpxGLd)

I found good solution for Bootstrap somewhere on this page. Here is the code. It works perfect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".carousel").swiperight(function() {
        $(this).carousel('prev');
    });
    $(".carousel").swipeleft(function() {
        $(this).carousel('next');
    });
});
```

but if I want this code include and modificate to code from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_imgdots) it won't work. So I tried something like this (It won't work in codepen I don't know why..)

```
$(function(){
            $( ".news-slide-content-img" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );
            $( ".news-slide-content-img" ).on( "swiperight", swiperightHandler );
            function swipeleftHandler( ){
                plusSlides(1).css('display', 'block');
            }
            function swiperightHandler( ){
                plusSlides(-1).css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
```

If I swipe it it swipe more images than one.

Any ideas how to solve this gesture problem?

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpxGLd)

Comment: well firstly in your codepen add this to `HTML`  -->   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">` at the top, that works perfectly.

Comment: I think you just have to wait for the `JS` to load maybe because it looks like its working.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't want include w3.css and i don't why I should include that.  Css and js (from w3school) is not problem. Problem is with jquery swipe gesture. It works bad with that code, or gesture works for you? @Ylama

Comment: No i understood wrong and couldnt remove my comment , i see now the swipe is not working..

Comment: It is a matter of jquery version. Consider my answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of jquery version. Using the documentation of the function [swipeleft](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/) and [swiperight](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/), these versions of jquery solve the issue:

```
src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
```

However, you also have a typo in the function `swipeleftHandler` and `swipeleftHandler`; you can consider these changes:

```
function swipeleftHandler( ){
    plusSlides(1);
  }
  function swiperightHandler( ){
    plusSlides(-1);
  }
```

You can have a look at this working snippet : https://codepen.io/edkeveked/pen/ypyJJX

Comment: Thank you. In my project I just edited function and finally it's working great. And in codepen was problem with jquery version, how you said. Thank you once again:)